# Why can't I use non-integral types with switch

Tags: c++, class, switch-statement, implicit-conversion

Cause if I define the `operator==` then comparison will be possible:

```
class My
{
    int x;
    // ...
public:
    My(int);

    bool operator==(const My & y);
        // ...
};

//...

My one = 1;
switch (one)
{
    case 1 : // anything

    default : // ...
}
```

But it's possible only for integer types. Why?

Comment: It is the rule of langauge

Comment: Because the language does not allow it.

Comment: I relize it. But which is a reason?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The BCPL and C languages implemented `switch` (`switchon` in BCPL) as a higher-level implementation of an [assembly branch table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_table).

A branch table is a very efficient implementation of an if/else chain that uses a single integer to index into an array of addresses (or address offsets).  Program control *jumps* to the address at the specified index of the table.

**`switch` requires an integer type (or a type implicitly convertible to an integer) because array-indexing requires an integer type.**

C++ inherited the same language properties of `switch` without making significant changes.

It would be *possible* to redefine the language to implement `switch` using `operator ==`, but that same behavior can already be implemented as an if/else chain.

Comment: It's not super hard to fake it either http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7259c4b5798daff7

Answer (score 3):

You can use classes in the switch statement.

According to the C++ Standard (6.4.2 The switch statement):

> 2 The condition shall be of integral type, enumeration type, or class
>   type. If of class type, the condition is contextually implicitly
>   converted (Clause 4) to an integral or enumeration type.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    int x;

public:
    A( int x ) : x( x ) {}

    operator int() const { return x; }
};

int main()
{
    A a( 2 );

    switch ( a )
    {
        case 1:
            std::cout << "past by" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            std::cout << "Bingo!" << std::endl;
            break;
    }            
}
```

The program output is

```
Bingo!
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an [implicit *conversion operator*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) to your class to make this possible:

```
operator int() const { return x; }
```