# How can I make a case statement based on an iterable?

Tags: c++, loops, switch-statement

I want to make a case statement based on an iterable, but I understand that the case expression must be a constant. What is a workaround for this?

I tried the below code, but it still does not work.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    while( i >= 0)
    {
        const int z = i;
        cout << "Enter a number other than " << z << "!\n";
        int choice;
        cin >> choice;
        switch(choice){
            case z: cout << "Hey! you weren't supposed to enter "<< z <<"!"; return 0; break;
            default: if(i==10)
                    {
                        cout << "Wow, you're more patient then I am, you win."; return 0;
                    }
                    break;
        }
        i++;
    }

}
```

Comment: `if (choice == z) {} else {}`....

Comment: Use if statements instead of switch-case

Comment: It's totally impossible with switch-case, because you have to give value known at compile time for case. Use `if {} else if {} else {}` pattern instead

Comment: `switch()` with one case is not more readable than `if else` anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`case` requires constant integral values known at compile-time.

So you'll have to use `if`-s:

```
if (choice == z) {
  cout << "Hey! you weren't supposed to enter "<< z <<"!";
  return 0;
} else if (i == 10) {
  cout << "Wow, you're more patient then I am, you win.";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: if, else sounds like the only option. I can remove z and just work with i now too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When a switch statement is encountered, the execution continues from from the corresponding case block all the way to the end of the switch statement unless a break is encountered. Therefore the switch statement is closer in "spirit" with an goto statement and not nested ifs. The implementation is also different and it is done using [assembly branch tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_table)  as explained here.

[Why can't I use non-integral types with switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31441541/why-cant-i-use-non-integral-types-with-switch)

Therefore, like Daniel Trugman said you need to use nested if statements.